# Python While Loop, also using modulo and continue commands

Tags: python, while-loop, modulo, continue

Attempting to finish this task that asks me to:

"Write a while loop that calculates the sum of the integers from 1 to 20 (inclusive), excluding those integers evenly divisible by 3. (Hint: You'll find the modulo operator (%) and the continue statement handy for this.)

I've attempted to construct the code myself, but the evaluation of the code times out. I'm guessing my syntax is incorrect and is causing an infinite loop

```
    total, x = 0, 1
    while x >=1 and x <= 20:
        if x%3==0:
            continue
        if x%3 != 0:
            print(x)
            x+=1
            total+=1
    print(total)
```

The expected answer should be:

20
19
17
16
14
13
11
10
8
7
5
4
2
1

But I just get 'Timed out' errors

***Latest::

Attempted this:

```
total, x = 0, 1
while x>=1 and x<=20:
    if x%3 == 0:
        x+=1
        continue
    if x%3 != 0:
       print(x)
       x+=1
       total=+1
print(total)
```

Received this::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/usr/src/app/test_methods.py", line 23, in test
    self.assertEqual(self._output(), "147\n")
AssertionError:     '1\n2\n4\n5\n7\n8\n10\n11\n13\n14\n16\n17\n19\n20\n1\n' != '147\n'
```

- 1
- 2
- 4
- 5
- 7
- 8
- 10
- 11
- 13
- 14
+ 147
?   +
- 16
- 17
- 19
- 20
- 1

Comment: Just run the loop till 20 since you are giving `x` value of 1, also `total += x` I guess so ?

Comment: You should do `x += 1` **outside** the `if` statement.

Comment: Or better yet, just do `for x in range(1,21)` and get rid of the `x += 1`.

Comment: Your `AssertionError` is not related to the piece of code you have shared. Also, try the code I have shared below in answer section.

Answer (score 5):

You are not incrementing `x` inside first `if` statement, hence it is stuck at that value and loops forever. You can try this.

```
total, x = 0, 1
while x >=1 and x <= 20:
    if x%3==0:
        x+=1  # incrementing x here
        continue
    elif x%3 != 0:  # using an else statement here would be recommended
        print(x)
        x+=1
        total+=x  # we are summing up all x's here
print(total)
```

Alternately, you can increment `x` outside if statements. You can use `range()` as well. Here, we are simply ignoring `x` which are divisible by `3`.

```
total, x = 0, 1
for x in range(1, 21):
    if x%3 != 0:
        print(x)
        x+=1
        total+=x
print(total)
```

Comment: for the second example you don't need to increment x in the for loop since the for x in range(1, 21) already handles that

Comment: Oh yes, such a stupid mistake! Thanks for pointing out @Chachmu.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
>>> lst = []
>>> while x >=1 and x <= 20:
    if x%3==0:
        x+=1  # this line solve your issue
        continue
    elif x%3 != 0:   # Use elif instead of if
        lst.append(x) # As your expected output is in reverse order, store in list
        x+=1
        total+=1
```

**One liner:** (Another way)

```
>>> [x for x in range(20,1,-1) if x%3 != 0]
[20, 19, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2]
```

---

**Output:**

```
>>> lst[::-1] # reverse it here
[20, 19, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 8, 7, 5, 4, 2, 1]
```